# Modify iPhone app store details

Tags: iphone, app-store

Once the iPhone app is in `Ready for Sale` status, then I want to change some details like support URL or keywords, would it change the status to `In Review` and again I will have to wait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only change the keywords when you change the binary!  We learned this the hard way after our first release.

Support URL and App Description can be changed at any time.

Comment: So are there any changes which will allow me to modify but will then change the status?

Answer (score 2):

Changing support URL or the app description will NOT change the status of the app. In fact, nothing will unless you explicitely remove the current version from the App Store or upload a new binary (and in that case the current version will remain on sale for the time being).

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit the following information:

> ```
> Copyright
> Description
> EULA
> Localization deletion
> Marketing URL
> Rights & Pricing
> Contact Email Address
> Support URL
> Privacy Policy URL
> Release Notes
> ```

You can only edit the following information if your app is in an editable state:

> ```
> Categories
> Keywords
> Large Icon
> Localization addition
> App Name
> Ratings
> Review Notes
> Screenshots
> Version Number
> Version Release Control
> ```

Editable states are:

> ```
> Prepare For Upload
> Waiting For Upload
> Waiting For Review
> Waiting For Export Compliance
> Upload Received
> Rejected
> Metadata Rejected
> Developer Rejected
> Invalid Binary
> Missing Screenshot (iOS only)
> ```

To make changes to your app's Rights and Pricing, In-App Purchases, Game Center, iAd Network settings, and Newsstand go to the app's App Summary page on the Manage Your Applications module. You can edit additional items on the app's Version Details page. Submitted changes should be visible on the App Store within 24 hours.